# Midleman check if local data exists

Tags: middleman

In Middleman, how can I know if a local variable exists? Local as a yaml variable. ([Follow this link to know more](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/local-data/))

For instance I can have:

```
row:
  first:>
    {some text}
  second:>
    {some text}
```

normally I would access it by `data.file_name.row.first` but what if I want to know if it exists?

`data.file_name.row.first.nil?` gives an error if does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error does it give? If you're getting a `NoMethodError`, try this:

```
data.file_name.try(:row).try(:first).nil?
```

Comment: It's odd. It seems to work most of the times. but in this scenario where I have markdown inside :first it gives me an error when `try`ing a nod inside it. The error is `undefined method image_url` if I try `data.file_name.row.first.try(:image_url)`